# Did CNN use a photo from Houston in a story about impacts of COVID-19 in San Francisco?

Tags: covid-19, media

In [a public post on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=2834632199924679&set=p.2834632199924679&type=3&hc_location=ufi) dated March 13, an individual named Jeremy Jack claims that his photo was misused by CNN "to incite mass hysteria around the issue" of COVID-19.

> Okay.. I have held my tongue about this COVID-19 insanity but after #CNN used MY face to report outright LIES that continue to incite the mass hysteria around this issue.. all bets are off! My son starts blowing up my phone today saying DAD you are on the news about the Corona Virus! I was completely confused.. so I find out that while reporting on the conditions in San Francisco as a result of the virus they used footage of ME and others during Hurricane Harvey in HOUSTON lined up outside of Kroger’s on Westheimer near the Beltway! CNN is using MY face to present misleading journalism that continues to seriously impact our economy and the every day decision making of the public. This is not okay.. do actual research for yourself. Get info from Health Organizations and local/national government. Take general safety precautions. Ignore the news..

This looks like a legitimate Facebook account, and I have no reason to doubt his claim that he appeared on CNN. However I'm left with doubts about the context in which his photo was actually used by CNN. Did CNN falsely suggest that these people were waiting in line for groceries in San Francisco due to COVID-19?

[image: screenshot from Faacebook]

Comment: He says later in the post "they used footage of ME and others during Hurricane Harvey in HOUSTON".  So while he may live in San Francisco now, he's asserting that the picture was taken in Houston in 2017.

Comment: I verified (with Google street view) that that is most likely the Kroger's in Houston.  And the guy on the left is apparently Jeremy Jack.  We don't know, however, what the context off the CNN story was.

Comment: The [author posted a note to fact checkers](https://www.facebook.com/jeremymjack/posts/2901365143251384).

Comment: (Bear in mind that the speaker may have been talking of prior "panics", such as may have occurred during Hurricane Harvey.  In which case the picture would have been entirely appropriate.)

Comment: Ironically, the report appears to be exactly about the fear created by media presentation of disasters, and about how to avoid the problems of it, thereby to reduce fear and panic, not engender more of it as criticised.